# broom::augment too slow with panel mixed model

Tags: r, tidyverse, panel-data

I would like to ask,

when doing mixed panel data models, and then retriving complete regression output using `broom::augment`

it is very slow as as oppose to different model such as random, fixed effect

example:

```
#Load packages
library(foreign)
library(plm)
library(stargazer)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(quantreg)

#Load in Wooldridge data on crime
crime <- read.dta("http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/crime4.dta")

#Declare our data to be a panel data set
crime.p <- pdata.frame(crime,index=c("county","year"))
crime.p %>% head

panel1 <- plm(crmrte ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density, data = crime.p, model = "within")
panel2 <- plm(crmrte ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density, data = crime.p, model = "random")
panel3 <- plm(crmrte ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density, data = crime.p, model = "pool")
panel4 <- rq(crmrte ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density + factor(county)-1, data = crime.p)
panel5 <- lmer(crmrte ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density + (1 | county), data = crime.p)

broom::augment(panel1)
broom::augment(panel2)
broom::augment(panel4)

# This one is very slow
broom::augment(panel5)
```

In this it is slow, however with bigger datasets it can took even 20 minutes,
is there a way how to retrive output that would be given by broom::augment(mixed) but much faster?

Comment: It is not slow on my machine at all. Actually it is very fast: `> system.time(broom::augment(panel5))
   user 0.02 system 0.00 elapsed 0.02`

Comment: ok, well I suppose is due to my computer, maybe R on server should be used

Comment: I am using RStudio Windows on my old laptop. I would try to update all packages including R and Rstudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`panel5` isn't particularly slow on my machine (~0.01seconds). You can see where the most time is taken by calculating each column separately and timing:

I created a custom function to calculate each of the elements of the `augment` result:

```r
fe <- function(panel){
  f <- fixef(panel)
  int <- f[1]
  coef <- f[-1]
  d <- panel5@frame
  d1 <- d[names(f) %in% names(d)]

  int + rowSums(mapply(`*`, d1, coef))
}

augment2 <- function(panel) {
  d <- panel@frame
  p <- predict(panel)
  r <- resid(panel)
  hat <- hatvalues(panel)
  cook <- cooks.distance(panel)
  fe <- fe(panel)
  mu <- panel@resp$mu
  wr <- panel@resp$wtres
  cbind(d,fitted=p,redidual = r,hat,cooksd=cook,fixed=fe,mu,wtres=wr)
}
```

If we time the two, they are pretty similar since all I've done is calculate the same things that `augment` calculates:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  augment = broom::augment(panel5),
  cust = augment2(panel5)
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# augment 12.332313 12.85186 16.83977 13.31599 15.69942 59.84045   100
#    cust  9.976812 10.38016 11.94285 10.66314 11.32606 43.50708   100
```

If we take out each of the columns in turn from our custom `augment2` function, we can see that most of the time is taken in calculating `hatvalues` and `cooks.distance`. If you don't really need one or both of these columns, it will speed your calculation up significantly. Excluding both, we can see a 25x increase in speed:

```r
augment3 <- function(panel) {
  d <- panel@frame
  p <- predict(panel)
  r <- resid(panel)
  #hat <- hatvalues(panel)
  #cook <- cooks.distance(panel)
  fe <- fe(panel)
  mu <- panel@resp$mu
  wr <- panel@resp$wtres
  cbind(d,fitted=p,redidual = r,fixed=fe,mu,wtres=wr)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  augment = broom::augment(panel5),
  cust = augment3(panel5)
)

#Unit: microseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq       max neval
# augment 12549.486 12924.666 17760.754 13341.712 15480.9555 87276.359   100
#    cust   406.818   474.119   694.698   532.005   586.5685  4702.398   100
```

Basically the time taken is due to `cooks.distance` and `hat.values` which I can't imagine could be calculated much more efficiently than they already are.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the silly question, but  when getting the results from augment(lmer) of a lmer model, you have .fitted, .resid, etc... but I cannot find what are the differences between the .fitted and the .fixed ? If I want to plot the predicted vales because of the lmer model, should I plot .fixed or .fitted ? Thanks